# Missing values remaining after applying sklearn SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I'm trying to handle missing values in a list of countries by replacing them with 'US':

```
imputer_const = SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="US")
imputed_X_temp=X_temp.copy()
imputed_X_temp["countryCode"] = pd.DataFrame(imputer_const.fit_transform(imputed_X_temp['countryCode'].array.reshape(-1, 1)))
imputed_X_temp.columns=X_temp.columns
```

but after checking with

```
print(" \nCount total NaN at each column in train data : \n\n", imputed_X_temp.isnull().sum())
```

I still have 10 missing values (vs. 27 before imputation). What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It may be an indexing problem caused by your dataframe'ing the transformed array. What's the shape before and after, and is your index just the default 0,...?

Answer (score 0):

```py
imputer_const = SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="US")
imputed_X_temp = X_temp.copy()
imputed_X_temp["countryCode"] = imputer_const.fit_transform(X_temp['countryCode'].values.reshape(-1, 1)))
```

If, after this, `imputed_X_temp` still has missing values, they're most likely from other columns.